# Remove the extra and not allowed characters from the ruby line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a line: `ggSuQNs6TxOTuQDd0j+4sA==$QO/Mq2jwfe3jgsGGoIGmlg==`. I need to 
transform it to `ggSuQNs6TxOTuQDd0j4sAQOMq2jwfe3jgsGGoIGmlg` (Only letters and numbers). Then trim it to 13 characters `ggSuQNs6TxOTu` and paste after 3 symbol the first half nubler of digits, paste after 9 symbol second half nubler of digits. For examle have number `3243` and string `ggSuQNs6TxOTu`. After have `ggS32uQNs436TxOTu`

My english is bad), i hope you understand me.

Comment: How are you tried to solve it?

Comment: Yep, any code or any idea from where to start? Take look into regex and `gsub` string's method, that would be a start.

Comment: It looks like 2 base64 strings concatenated together. Are you sure you wanna remove non-word characters and make the string mean nothing?

Comment: @Alex Golubenko tried to use split with regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my try as what I could understand from your question (Let me go through with your each sentences).

Your string:

```
s = "ggSuQNs6TxOTuQDd0j+4sA==$QO/Mq2jwfe3jgsGGoIGmlg=="
```

**Step-1**

> I need to transform it to
>   "ggSuQNs6TxOTuQDd0j4sAQOMq2jwfe3jgsGGoIGmlg" (Only letters and
>   numbers).

only characters and digits:

```
 > transform_string = s.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')
 #=> "ggSuQNs6TxOTuQDd0j4sAQOMq2jwfe3jgsGGoIGmlg"
```

**Step -2**

> Then trim it to 13 characters "ggSuQNs6TxOTu"

fetch first 13 characters like this way:

```
 > thirteen_chrs = transform_string[0..12]
 #=> "ggSuQNs6TxOTu"
```

**Step-3** (from your example)

```
number = 3242
```

**Step-4**

> after 3 characters the first half number of digits, paste after 9
>   characters second half number of digits.

here is in-line code for same:

```
> thirteen_chrs.insert(3, number.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join).first).insert(9, number.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join).last)
#=> "ggS3232uQ42Ns6TxOTu"
```

I hope this may help you :)